# Grouped Cross-validation LassoCV scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, internal

I am running into some weird errors using the LassoCV() regressor in combination with a grouped cross-validation object.

More specific, having dataframe `df` and target column `y`, I would like to perform LeaveOneGroupOut() cross-validation. If I run the following:

```
df = np.random.rand(100,50)
y = np.random.rand(100)
logo = LeaveOneGroupOut()
groups = np.random.randint(0,10,100)
lassoCV = linear_model.LassoCV(eps=0.0001, n_alphas=400, max_iter=200000, cv=logo, normalize=False, random_state=9) `
```

Running:

```
lassoCV.fit(df,y)
```

results in the error: `ValueError: The 'groups' parameter should not be None.`

If I run:

```
lassoCV.fit(df,y,groups)
```

I get the error: `TypeError: fit() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given`.

Seems to me that the second option would be the way to go. Did I implement something wrong? Or is this a bug in scikit-learn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `groups` error refers to the parameter in your `LeaveOneGroupOut`'s split method. Per the documentation referenced [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html), the `cv` argument should be an iterable  that yields train/test splits. Therefore, you just need to create the generator object using the [`split`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneGroupOut.html) method.

```
gen_logo = logo.split(df, groups=groups)  # create your generator
lassoCV = linear_model.LassoCV(eps=0.0001, n_alphas=400, max_iter=200000, cv=gen_logo, normalize=False, random_state=9)  # pass it to the cv argument
lassoCV.fit(df, y)  # now fit
```

Comment: Second question, how come then if I use the function `cross_val_predict()` I have to use it as follows:

     `alpha = LassoCV.alpha
     lasso = Lasso(alpha,max_iter=20000,normalize=False)
     cross_val_predict(lasso, df, y,cv=LeaveOneGroupOut(),groups=groups)`

as the following gives me an error: 


   `cross_val_predict(lasso, df, y, cv=gen_logo)`

Comment: Because gen_logo is an generator object, so once it is exhausted, it returns nothing else when called again to produce the next element. You would have to recreate the generator object and then pass it as the `cv` argument. Thus, run `gen_logo = logo.split(df, groups=groups)`, and then call `cross_val_predict(lasso, df, y, cv=gen_logo)`. Here's a good [article](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/) on generators.